# Sharepoint Online JSON for Conditional Date Formatting

Tags: json, date, sharepoint-online

I am attempting to format some columns in a SharePoint Online list using JSON. I've gotten this close to where I want it through simple column formatting so that items that were due before today show up red highlighted, items due today are gold. My challenge is that I only want items due tomorrow to be green - items due after tomorrow should get no highlighting.  But honestly, I'm completely confused as to how to do this.

The auto-generated code is as follows:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "0 2px",
    "overflow": "hidden",
    "text-overflow": "ellipsis"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": {
      "operator": ":",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "==",
          "operands": [
            "@currentField",
            ""
          ]
        },
        "",
        {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "<",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "Date()",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "toDateString()",
                      "operands": [
                        "@currentField"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "operator": "Date()",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "toDateString()",
                      "operands": [
                        "@now"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgRed sp-css-borderColor-WhiteFont sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-WhiteFont",
            {
              "operator": ":",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "==",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "Date()",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": "toDateString()",
                          "operands": [
                            "@currentField"
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "operator": "Date()",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": "toDateString()",
                          "operands": [
                            "@now"
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgGold sp-css-borderColor-GoldFont sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-GoldFont",
                {
                  "operator": ":",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "==",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": "Date()",
                          "operands": [
                            {
                              "operator": "toDateString()",
                              "operands": [
                                "@currentField"
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "operator": "Date()",
                          "operands": [
                            {
                              "operator": "toDateString()",
                              "operands": [
                                "@now"
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMintGreen sp-css-borderColor-MintGreenFont sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-MintGreenFont",
                    ""
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "txtContent": "@currentField.displayValue"
}
```

I know the issue and what I have to fix is in this block:

```
{
                          "operator": "Date()",
                          "operands": [
                            {
                              "operator": "toDateString()",
                              "operands": [
                                "@now"
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
```

as I need to add 84600000 to the @now to calculate tomorrow, but I'll be damned if I can find the right syntax to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried

```
{
                          "operator": "Date()",
                          "operands": [
                            {
                              "operator": "toDateString()",
                              "operands": [
                                "@now",84600000
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
```

But its definitely not that simple.